# Compare values ​of an array and an object and save them to another object if true

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am looking to compare two arrays and create a new object based on the information and comparisons that are true, I explain below.

My goal is to get the *codes* that I saved in the **codes array** and compare it with the **imagesCode.code object**, if they are *the same*, I get the **codes.title and codes.rgb1** passes it to **imagesCode.title and imagesCode.rgb**, so I I can take this **new object and return it completely** for use

**getImagesObj**

```
const colors = 'http://api.evoximages.com/api/v1/vehicles/';
const urlsColors = res.data.data[0]["urls"];
        try {
            colorList = await axios.get(colors);

            let codes = [];
            let codesLength = 0;
            let imagesCode = {
                code,
                url,
                title,
                rgb
            };

            for (let i = 0; i < colorList.data.data.colors.length; i++) {
               codesLength = colorList.data.data.colors[0].code.length;
               codes.push(colorList.data.data.colors[i]);   
               imagesCode.code = urlsColors[i].substr(-4 - codesLength, codesLength);
               imagesCode.url = urlsColors[i];
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < imagesCode.length; j++) {
            if (imagesCode.code == codes[j].code) {
                imagesCode.title = codes[j].title;
                imagesCode.rgb = codes[j].rgb1;
            } else {
              console.log("something wrong");
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
```

In *the first for* he does *not save the elements inside the object*, I am not very familiar, I just tried, in *the second for* he was *to check and compare the codes*, if they **are true** I would **pass the titles and rgb**, but I failed again

**Example of codes array:**

```
[{
    vifnum: 12930,
    code: 'GPJ',
    title: 'Cajun Red Tintcoat',
    simpletitle: 'Red',
    rgb1: '86090C',
    rgb2: null,
    shotin: 1,
    id: 5099113
  },
  {
    vifnum: 12930,
    code: 'G1W',
    title: 'Iridescent Pearl Tricoat',
    simpletitle: 'White',
    rgb1: 'E8E8EE',
    rgb2: null,
    shotin: 0,
    id: 5099114
  },
  {
    vifnum: 12930,
    code: 'G8U',
    title: 'Ivy Metallic',
    simpletitle: 'Green',
    rgb1: '0C321D',
    rgb2: null,
    shotin: 0,
    id: 5099115
  },
  {
    vifnum: 12930,
    code: 'GD1',
    title: 'Kinetic Blue Metallic',
    simpletitle: 'Blue',
    rgb1: '223968',
    rgb2: null,
    shotin: 0,
    id: 5099116
  },
  {
    vifnum: 12930,
    code: 'GB8',
    title: 'Mosaic Black Metallic',
    simpletitle: 'Black',
    rgb1: '060606',
    rgb2: null,
    shotin: 0,
    id: 5099117
  }
]
```

**Example of imagesCode array:**

```
['G1W', 'G8U', 'GB8', 'GD1', 'GPJ']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
imagesCode=['G1W', 'G8U', 'GB8', 'GD1', 'GPJ']
codes=imagesCode = [{
    vifnum: 12930,
    code: 'GPJ',
    title: 'Cajun Red Tintcoat',
    simpletitle: 'Red',
    rgb1: '86090C',
    rgb2: null,
    shotin: 1,
    id: 5099113
  },
  {
    vifnum: 12930,
    code: 'G1W',
    title: 'Iridescent Pearl Tricoat',
    simpletitle: 'White',
    rgb1: 'E8E8EE',
    rgb2: null,
    shotin: 0,
    id: 5099114
  },
  {
    vifnum: 12930,
    code: 'G8U',
    title: 'Ivy Metallic',
    simpletitle: 'Green',
    rgb1: '0C321D',
    rgb2: null,
    shotin: 0,
    id: 5099115
  },
  {
    vifnum: 12930,
    code: 'GD1',
    title: 'Kinetic Blue Metallic',
    simpletitle: 'Blue',
    rgb1: '223968',
    rgb2: null,
    shotin: 0,
    id: 5099116
  },
  {
    vifnum: 12930,
    code: 'GB8',
    title: 'Mosaic Black Metallic',
    simpletitle: 'Black',
    rgb1: '060606',
    rgb2: null,
    shotin: 0,
    id: 5099117
  }
]

for (var j = 0; j < imagesCode.length; j++) {
  if (imagesCode[j].code == codes[j].code) {
    console.log(codes[j].code + " = " + imagesCode[j].code) // Dit not work
  } else {
    console.log("something wrong");
  }
}
```

Comment: what i get in codes is the return of the api, i can't pass predefined

Comment: API? Now I'm confused - you didn't mention anything about an API in your question.

Comment: I will redo my question more objectively and show you what I really want to do

Answer (score 1):

```
const results = ImagesCodes.map((code) => ({
  code,
  title: ObjCodes.find((item) => item.code === code)?.title
}));
```

Comment: I will redo my question more objectively and show you what I really want to do

Comment: That's not very clear, can you do data1, data2 and what results should look like?

Comment: I added examples of the two arrays